# How to write custom django manage.py commands in multiple apps

Tags: python, django, django-admin, manage.py

Imagine I have two or more apps in my django project, I was able to successfully write and execute custom manage.py commands when I had only one app, `A`.

Now I have a new app, `B`, and as mentioned in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/ I created directory structure of `B/manangement/commands` and wrote a custom module.

When I run python manage.py , it keeps complaining `Unknown command`. However if I move this command to other app, i.e. to folder `A/management/commands` and then run `python manage.py <command>`, it works seamlessly.

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: Not without you showing us exactly what you've done.

Comment: Probably you haven't added B in the installed app in settings.

Comment: I guess is a typo but better pointing it out. The word 'manangement' is misspelled.

Comment: just for the record: I had the same command in to apps (yeah, blame me) and only the command of the app first mentioned in the INSTALLED_APPS list is recognized.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As @Babu said in the comments, It looks like you may not have added your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`.

It's also possible that you're missing the `__init__.py` files (that are required in python modules) from the `management` and `commands` folders.

Alternatively, (sorry to say this) you may have misspelt "management" or "commands", or even the name of the command you're running.

Comment: Thanks, the __init__.py files were there in the inner directories, missed in the higher directory.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you did not include app B in your settings.py

If you just run `python manage.py` with no command specified, it will print the list of commands Django can find.

This can help rule out misspelling the command name, but doesn't answer the question of whether or not you made `management` and `commands` both packages, or if app B simply isn't listed in your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not registered your **app B** in **INSTALLED_APPS** in our **settings.py**.
You also need to add a **__init__.py** file in both folders(**management** and **commands**) to make it as a package. Make Sure you spell folder names correctly.